# showing a different component on state change and for loop React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting started with react js, and I am facing 2 problems.

1) I am trying to show a table which is in a different class, by clicking show button , a table should show up. The problem is that, the table doesnt show up even if the state is true for showing the table.

2) In the table I am passing an array with information like this

```
Object {1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object}

1 capital_payment :"100", 
    currency: "2" 
    dudedate : "2017-08-20"
```

But I am not sure how to use a for loop and render those information. I am using a console.log to see whats inside but my code doesnt even go till showing the new class to show the table.

Here are the codes.

```
var Heading = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        data : [],
         amount : 1000,
         firstMonth : 0,
         showtable : false <--------- HERE IS THE SHOW TABLE STATE
      };
  },
    showTable : function(){
      console.log('I am here');
      this.setState({showtable : !this.state.showtable}); <----CHANGING STATE HERE
      console.log(this.state.showtable);
    },
    render : function(){
      var amount = this.state.amount;
      var firstMonth = this.state.firstMonth;
      return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>How much <span>{amount}</span> </label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Amount" value={amount} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.loadCommentsFromServer} >Submit</button>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" onClick = {this.showTable} > Show table </button>
                <hr />
            <!--- HERE IS WHERE THE NEW CLASS SHOULD SHOW UP IF TABLE IS CHANGED -->
                { this.state.showtable ? <tableView data={this.state.data}/> : null }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
});
// HERE IS THE TABLEVIEW, AND I HAVE NO CLUE HOW TO DO A FOR LOOP TO RENDER INFORMATION TO THE TABLE
var tableView = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      console.log(this.props.data);
        return (
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>amount</th>
                <th>duedate</th>
                <th>currency</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
              <!-- Need to know how the forloop is done, is there a easier way? -->
              {this.props.data.map(function(info) {
                return (
                  <tr key={info}>
                    {info.capital_payment},
                    {info.currency},
                    {info.duedate}
                  </tr>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Heading
    name="React JS"
    >
    </Heading>
    <tableView />
    </div>
, document.getElementById('reactBinding'));
```

Comment: What you did with map in TableView it's a normal practice. Why table didn't show? Any errors?

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure why the table doesnt show up, and I just used a forloop from another stack over flow post following it. No there is no error. I console logged the statechange, and it shows true and false, if the button for show table is clicked but the table doesnt appear. I dont even get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `react` component with small letters starting, they are treated as `HTML` elements, your component will not get rendered in that case, so its a rule that all `React` components must starts with a upper case letter, so always use Upper Case.

instead of `tableview` use `TableView`.

One more thing data that you pasted in ques, showed that your data is not an array, its an object with keys 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6:

`Object {1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object}`

To use map it should be like this:

`[{}, {}, {}, {}...]`

or if you data is like this only then you need to use map on the keys of the `object`, like this:

```
Object.keys(this.props.data).map((key,i)=>{
     console.log(this.props.data[key])
})
```

When you use Object.keys() it will return an array of all the keys: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

After that you can use map on that.

Check the working code with data as an object:

```js
var Heading = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        data : {1: {a:1,b:1,c:1}, 2: {a:2,b:2,c:2}, 3:{a:3,b:3,c:3}},
         amount : 1000,
         firstMonth : 0,
         showtable : false 
      };
  },
    showTable : function(){
      this.setState({showtable : !this.state.showtable});
    },
    render : function(){
      var amount = this.state.amount;
      var firstMonth = this.state.firstMonth;
      return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>How much <span>{amount}</span> </label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Amount" value={amount} onChange={this.handleChange} />
              </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.loadCommentsFromServer} >Submit</button>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" onClick = {this.showTable} > Show table </button>
                <hr />
                { this.state.showtable ? <TableView data={this.state.data}/> : null }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
});

var TableView = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      let data = this.props.data;
        return (
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>amount</th>
                <th>duedate</th>
                <th>currency</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Object.keys(data).map((key) =>                            {
                return (
                  <tr key={key}>
                    <td> a: {data[key].a} </td>
                    <td> b: {data[key].b} </td>
                    <td> c: {data[key].c} </td>
                  </tr>
                  );
                })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Heading
    name="React JS"
    >
    </Heading>
    </div>
, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```

**How to use `Object.keys` and its meaning**:

When we use `Object.keys` it returns an array that contains all the keys of that object. Run this snippet and check the output:

```js
obj = {a:1 , b:2 , c:3 , d:4};

keys = Object.keys(obj);

console.log('keys', keys);

values = Object.values(obj);

console.log('values', values);
```

Comment: Is there anyway for me to fix it ?

Comment: Hey your suggestion is actually working!! Can you show me how to use object.keys with map to ouput the values in table. 
Sorry for asking too much but I am getting overly confused :(

Comment: check the updated answer, how to use `Object.keys`, let me know if you need any other help :)

Comment: Nice! It works! Thanks! But why is it all in one column?

Comment: i use the same code that you pasted in ques, you used only one tr thats why. put the data inside `<td>`.

Comment: Ahh okay sorry, I dint know how to put them in different <td> can you show me how its done? Like put them on multiple td?

Comment: Its still in the same column :(

Comment: check the updated answer, because you used a extra  `<tr>` before map, means all the output returned by map was going inside one `tr` and u needed to create `tr` by map. just removed that `tr` and its working :)

Comment: glad, to help you :)